# Getting text from textfile from server into textview not working

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to show the status of something. This is done by saving the status in a textfile (Either online or offline) called status.txt

I then use this code:

```
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
    URL url = new URL("mywebsite.net/subfolder/status.txt");

    // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        onlineStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        onlineStatus.setText(str);
    }

    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}

}
};
```

Nothing seems to happen, the app does not crash.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
URL url = new URL("http://mywebsite.net/subfolder/status.txt");
```

Also as good practice never completely ignore the thrown exceptions. Print the stacktrace at the very least. This is very helpful in the long term.
In your case maybe set the text to some generic error message.

Even after this, don't set the text in the while loop if you want to set the whole content in the text view.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace in that case ?